website navigation to accommodate both products and services -
I am working on revamping a website for a salon with several locations that allows users to book appointments online as well as shop their product line. Currently, the revenue from the sale of products, in general, makes up a very small percentage compared to service appointments (and % from products purchased on the website, as opposed to in the shop during their appointment, is even smaller). We're not positive that online product sales can be improved upon (without other MAJOR changes in several areas), but that is one objective of the revamp... without seeing any decline in the # of appointments booked online.
Currently, for new visitors, around 70% of page views are for things salon-related (locations, stylists, services, etc), 25% is product-related (including shopping cart and checkout) and the other 5% is company info and blog. Even more skewed in those directions for returning users.
The current global navigation looks like this (only horizontally)
_ Salon
|_ Services
|_ Locations
|_ Stylists
|_ BOOK NOW

_ Shop
|_ Megamenu with all categories and featured products

_ Discover
|_ This Blog Category
|_ That Blog Category
|_ The Other Blog Category

_ About
|_ Our Story
|_ Press
|_ Contact 

And a large BOOK NOW call to action button on the far right end of the header along with the shopping cart and login/profile icons.

...
My first inclination is to cut the global nav down considerably by removing the last 2 items (moving them to the footer) so that there is only Salon and Grooming Products (or something similar), each with the same dropdown menus they currently have, along with the stuff currently on the far right. I doubt that alone will be sufficient to increase product sales, but perhaps it will at least increase traffic to the category and product pages... which will at least be a start.
_ Salon
|_ Services
|_ Locations
|_ Stylists
|_ BOOK NOW

_ Shop
|_ Megamenu with all categories and featured products

And a large BOOK NOW call to action button on the far right end of the header along with the shopping cart and login/profile icons.

...
On the other hand, maybe 'Shop' is ubiquitous enough that anyone remotely interested in shopping for product will see it in a horizontal menu with a few other items. Those other items would be all of the items in Salon's dropdown menu above. So it might lok something like:
_ Services

_ Locations

_ Stylists

_ BOOK NOW (this might be bold, have a highlighted color and/or be in all caps)

_ SHOP (this might be bold, have a highlighted color and/or be in all caps)
|_ Megamenu with all categories and featured products

shopping cart and login/profile icons to the far right

...
From a cognition standpoint, is it better to visually separate the salon-related content links from the product-related content links so that anyone interested in "shopping" doesn't have to wade  through the Salon stuff in order to start viewing the Products (or at least the categories) they're interested in? And if so, would putting anything other than the equivalent of a SHOP NOW call to action on the right side of the header (near the shopping cart and login/profile icons/links) be in violation of that? Should they be 2 distinct workflows?

I think you are analyzing all the navigation in a way that is too classic, subordinating everything to a menu. Perhaps it would be helpful to visualize a more immersive type of navigation, giving priority to the totality of what the business offers.

In my opinion, there are only two menu options: Home and
Store
The home page has all the options of the hair salon plus some
featured products for sale
The sections of products for sale have links to the online store from
any of its items and titles
I would place the hamburger menu as a secondary element whose content
is the options most frequented by customers + the online store
I would think of mobile mode, with greater preponderance to visual
elements (always the menu as something secondary)



Yes i definitely come from the "classic" times .  And it's hard for me to wrap my head around not having the entitle site exist with this hierarchical menu structure as it's skeleton. I had considered doing 2 menu items, Salon and Store and putting everything else into a hamburger. Yours is similar/better, I suppose. I keep coming back to the potential issue of mixing shopping and scheduling in the upper right. Might that Book Now button be interfering from shopping-related tasks?

You can put the "Book Now" button next to the logo and the shopping bag on the opposite side so they don't interfere. Or simplify everything into two buttons: "Book Now" and "Buy Now"
